# Flutter: multi screen registration process

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have to implement a multi screen registration process for my app. This process is coposed by **CredentialsScreen** and **AnagraphicsScreen** (and those two screen must share the same AppBar);

On CredentialsScreen user set username and password, and after a remote call for check username availability, user will insert his anagraphics (name, birthday and so on), and then launch a registration call to my service.

This is my actual code for show CredentialsScreen, but i don't know ho to go to AnagraphicsScreen

```
class RegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _RegistrationScreenState();
}

class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: MyColor.appBackground,
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Center(
            child: BlocBuilder<RegistrationBloc, RegistrationState>(
                builder: (context, state) {  
                    if (state is RegistrationInitialState) {
                        return CredentialsScreen();
                    } else if (state is RegistrationUsernameAvailable) {
                        return AnagraphicsScreen();
                    }
                    return Container();
                },
             ),
           ),
        ),
      );
    }
}
```

I know that this implementation is wrong, also because on AnagraphicsScreen if i go back, i don't go on CredentialScreen but on my app main page.

Answer (score 0):

Try `IndexedStack` and change the index number accordingly.
e.g

```
IndexedStack(
  index: currentIndex,
  children: [
    CredentialsScreen(),
    AnagraphicsScreen()
     ]
  )
```